# Update state from a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component for my App. When the component is mounted I need to run a function `getOrder` to check with our database if such order exists. If it is found, I need to update the state with the data from the order.

Function `getOrder` is used in several places, so I would like to move it to a separate file.

Here is what I have now:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  }

  getOrder = async () => {
    axios.post('', {})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data.result === true) {
        let result = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
        this.setState({data: result});
      } else {
        alert("Order is not found");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getOrder()
  }

  render() {
    return (</>);
  }
}
```

I would like to move function `getOrder` outside the component like this:

```
const getOrder = async () => {
  axios.post('', {})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data.result === true) {
      let result = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
      this.setState({data: result});
    } else {
      alert("Order is not found");
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await getOrder()
  }

  render() {
    return (</>);
  }
}
```

How can I update the state of the App from the function `getOrder` in this case?

Comment: Why not `return JSON.parse(...)` from the promise chain, then use it *inside* the component: `getOrder().then((data) => this.setState({ data });`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please post an answer with a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: *don't* update state from outside a component. That leads to tight coupling that makes it hard to extend, refactor and test your components.

---

To refactor this you need to think about which parts of your code are related to fetching order data, and which are related to rendering the outcome. Try not to let transport-related details (HTTP statuses, body parsing, etc.) leak out into your components, for example, or display things to the user from your services.

Also I would generally avoid mixing `async`/`await` syntax with `.then`/`.catch` - at least within each function you should stick to one or the other.

Here's one way to rearrange it, where `getOrder` returns a promise that either resolves with the parsed data, or rejects with an error message:

```
const getOrder = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post('', {});
  if (response.data.result) {
    return JSON.parse(response.data.data);
  }
  throw new Error("Order is not found");
};
```

Now the component only deals with displaying that data, or the error:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {}
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const data = await getOrder();
      this.setState({ data });
    } catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (</>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try it. Could you please point me where I can read about the difference between `async/await` and `.then/.catch` syntax? One more question, is there any way to rearrange `getOrder` with react hooks?

Comment: 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await. 2. Not in a class-based component, but `getOrder` here doesn't know anything about React, it doesn't care where you call it from (e.g. `useEffect`).

Comment: 1. Thank you very much! 2. So if I change it to a functional component it will be possible?

Answer (score -1):

As all refactors: you pass in everything you need as function arguments.

So in this case, you pass a reference to the component as a function argument so you can call everything that used to be `this.[...]` as `component.[...]` instead. Also, because you've moved this function into global/module scope, don't use a `const blah = arrow function`: there is no `this` that needs (or *can*, even) be preserved. Instead, use a normal `function getOrder(component, ...) { ...}` and then call `component.setState(...)` in that function once you have the relevant data.

Finally, I would also recommend renaming the function: `getOrder` doesn't tell anyone what this function does, and as it's no longer contextual to a specific component, it probably should be self-explanatory in its name.

Comment: Could you please add a code example to your answer?

Comment: 1. Passing the component as an argument here exposes its whole interface to the function, which doesn't feel like great design. Also, what if something that *isn't* a component needs to fetch an order's data? 2. The choice of arrow vs. regular function in the module scope is largely a style choice. 3. If the term order is well understood in the domain, and what that function does is get an order, `getOrder` seems like it *is* self-explanatory.